# PHP displaying mysql log table in iframe with next and prev button

Tags: javascript, php, session, getelementbyid

I'm calling viewlog.php which display the xx rows of log table in a frame
The viewlog.php SQl call work.
no issue initializing the $_SESSION
I'm trying to add a next and prev button using a function that increase or decreased $_SESSION['offset']

```
<input type="button" value=" < PREV " onclick="PIframe();"> 
<input type="button" value = " NEXT >" onclick="NIframe();">
<iframe src="viewlog.php?os=<?php echo $_SESSION['offset']."&osl=" . $_SESSION['limit'];?>" name="LogIframe" id="LogIframe" />
</iframe
```

I'm 100% sure the Viewlog.php is getting the value of &_SESSION['offset']

My problem is

1. I'm not sure if the function  are being executed
2. I'm not sure if the $_SESSION['offset'] is being updated
3. I don't think document.getElementById is being run

   ```
   <?php
   function NIframe() {
       $_SESSION['offset'] = $_SESSION['offset'] + $_SESSION['limit'];     
       document.getElementById('LogIframe').contentWindow.location.reload();
   }

   function PIframe() {
       $_SESSION['offset'] = $_SESSION['offset'] - $_SESSION['limit'];     
       document.getElementById('LogIframe').contentWindow.location.reload();
   }
   ?>
   ```

I tried converting the Function to Javascript. The reload works but the $_SESSION is not being updated

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
function NIframe() {
<?php 
  $_SESSION['offset'] = $_SESSION['offset'] + $_SESSION['setofLimit'];
?> 
    document.getElementById('LogIframe').contentWindow.location.reload();
}
</script>
```

Help

Comment: The PHP code in your `NIframe()`-function will _always_ be executed since PHP get's executed on the server, before anything is send to the browser where your browser executes the JS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: `document.getElementById` is never executed by PHP